# A question about the number of generators of an ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

Is the number of generators of an ideal always constant? I can't seem to find an online reference that proves/disproves this fact. It would be easy to prove in linear algebra, but this case is obviously more complicated.

What if the ideal belongs to a Noetherian ring? Is the answer different for a commutative ring?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. Take $\mathbb Z$ - the whole ring is an ideal generated by $1$. But it is also generated by $\{2,3\}$ and you can't drop either $2$ or $3$, or try $\{6,10,15\}$.  So are you excluding such cases? How?

Comment: Do you mean the minimal number of generators perhaps?

Comment: @Prometheus- Yes

Comment: @Prometheus For a finitely generated Ideal the minimal number of generators is a well-defined constant integer. In a finitely generated vector space if you have more vectors than the dimension then some are linearly dependent on the others and can be dropped without changing the span of the set. This is not true for more general rings.

Comment: @Mark: given a set of generators for an ideal, one could ask for the minimal set of generators contained within that, similar to finding a basis inside a spanning set in a vector space. Is it obvious that minimal set will always have the same size?

Comment: @Prometheus See the example in my comment and continue $\{30,42,70,105\}$ - you can create a set of generators for $\mathbb Z$ of arbitrary finite size such that no subset will generate $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Mark: Yes, you're right.